# Classification with Matlab. Recognize classes in the test set

Tags: matlab, dataset, machine-learning

I have a situation that seems trivial but I can't figure it out. I have a dataset in Matlab that has categorical values. For example:

```
Outlook,Temperature,Humidity,Windy,Play
sunny,hot,high,false,no
sunny,hot,high,true,no
overcast,hot,high,false,yes
rainy,mild,high,false,yes
rainy,cool,normal,false,yes
rainy,cool,normal,true,no
overcast,cool,normal,true,yes
```

In order to use ClassificationTree (or other algorithm in machine learning), I need to convert the dataset to a matrix. I use (assuming that *data* contains the dataset):

```
double(data)
```

which assigns numbers to the values. Let's say rainy=1, overcast=2, sunny=3 and so on. I train the ClassificationTree and it works fine. But here is my problem. If I want to predict on test data:

```
overcast,cool,normal,false,yes
```

I need to know the numbers that double() assigned to each of the categories. i.e. overcast=2. Using double() on the test set does not work because there is no guarantee that the numbers assigned by double() are the same to those assigned to the *training* dataset.

I have found a really twisted way of doing it. For example, for Outlook:

```
d = zeros(size(test));
ls = getlevels(training.Outlook);
n = size(ls,2);
for i = 1:n
    d(test.Outlook == ls(i),1) = i;
end
```

Which assigns the numbers correctly because I check against each of the values for Outlook that I found in the *training* dataset. This is far from elegant, and there has to be something better.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "you usually don't use 1/2/3 for sunny/rainy/overcast, but ..."
classregtree() expects categorical predictors to be single columns with distinct numeric values for each category.  See 'help classregtree'.

Comment: Predictor is right. I'm sure of doing the right thing regarding the training set. The test set is the problem. I guess that I'll do it my way.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search through 'help dataset', etc. did not turn up a definitive answer for me.  My guess is that they are ordered as per unique() or something similar.  You may want to contact technical support at the Mathworks to be certain.